# Why is this public address different for an ethereum signature?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ethereum, nethereum

I have a signature created using metamask and the `personal_sign` RPC method.
Now I want to verify this signature in my C# backend.
In order to do so I have found the [Nethereum library](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum).
I have written the below code trying to verify the signature (for now I have used 'test' as the signed message).

```
public void VerifySignature(string signatureString, string originalMessage)
{
        string msg = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + originalMessage.Length + originalMessage;
        byte[] msgHash = new Sha3Keccack().CalculateHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg));

        EthECDSASignature signature = MessageSigner.ExtractEcdsaSignature(signatureString);

        EthECKey key = EthECKey.RecoverFromSignature(signature, msgHash);   
        bool isValid = key.Verify(msgHash, signature);
}
```

Now the `isValid` comes back as true. However, if I use `key.GetPublicAddress()` this address is different than my own public address, so I assume I'm doing something wrong. Can anyone explain to me what, or correct if I'm wrong?

NOTE:

If instead of

```
EthECKey testKey = EthECKey.RecoverFromSignature(signature, msgHash);
```

I use

```
EthECKey testKey = EthECKey.RecoverFromSignature(signature, msgHash, new BigInteger(1));
```

(I'm using the main network to sign which is chain 1)
I get an error saying "recId should be positive", not sure if this is related but I thought it's worth mentioning.

UPDATE:

Managed to fix this by changing the msg string to use `"\x19" + "Ethereum ..."` instead of `"\x19Ethereum ..."`, `\x19E` results in a different character, and results in a different message hash.

Answer (score 4):

Ethereum addresses and public keys represent two different things. An Ethereum address is the last 20 bytes of the Keccak-256 hash of the corresponding ECDSA (secp256k1) public key.

For more information, see https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/accounts/.